# Creating individual View Controllers for each view iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit, viewcontroller

This is a very simple simple question, and I believe the answer is “yes, it’s a best practice,” but I just wanted to ask the question.

When creating new views in your storyboard in Xcode, is it a good idea to create individual custom view controller files to handle each view specifically?

Meaning, if I create a new view called “login quiz,” should I create a “loginQuizViewController” that will handle all the code I write for that view?

Comment: FWIW, as a matter of convention, class names start with uppercase letter, e.g. `LoginQuizViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes, each storyboard scene generally has a unique view controller class associated with it. A view controller has a root [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view), which in turn may have many subviews below that, and each subview might have further  subviews. This collection of views is collectively known as the “view hierarchy”.

---

**Long answer:**

Yes, each [storyboard “scene”](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev62c993289) has a view controller associated with it. And generally this view controller class is a particular `UIViewController` subclass which is unique to that particular Interface Builder scene. But you don’t necessarily have to have a view controller subclass and might, for example, use one of the existing classes (e.g. this is not uncommon for navigation controller scenes or tab bar controller scenes).

But if you have *any* custom logic associated with a particular storyboard scene, then, yes, you would generally have a unique view controller subclass for that particular scene.

Two minor clarifications:

- You refer to the “quiz view”.

  That’s fine for colloquial purposes, but for the sake of clarity, when we’re talking about everything for this quiz, it’s really a complex hierarchy of views, not just a one.

  A single “quiz” scene will be associated with a unique view controller class, and the instance of that view controller class will have a single “root view” (identified with the [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view) property), but that `view` will have a whole bunch of subviews (e.g. image views, buttons, labels, etc.), and some of those may have subviews of their own.

  So one storyboard scene has its own unique view controller class, but is associated with a whole hierarchy of views.
- We often think of a scene, and its associated view controller, as representing everything you might see at any given point in time, but it’s not always a one-to-one relationship. Sometimes what you see is composed of several storyboard scenes and their respective view controllers.

  For example, if you are using a navigation controller, the navigation controller takes care of the navigation bar at the top, and your view controller might take care of everything under the navigation bar. What is visible on screen is composed of these two view controllers.

  Or, in a more extreme example, we can define our own [view controller containers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller). In the example below, when we present A, we can define the bottom half of the screen to be managed by a completely separate scene, B, which has its own view controller:

  [image]

  In this case, both A and B have their own IB scenes and their own respective view controllers. Achieve this by adding a “container view” to the A scene (the light blue `UIView` in the above screen snapshot).

  But the main point is that what you see on screen may be captured by a single storyboard scene and view controller, or it might be composed of several.

Comment: Thanks Rob! That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you for taking time to explain the long version for me too!

Comment: @Rob, I upvoted your great answer. One question: *"Yes, each storyboard scene **generally** has a unique view controller class associated with it."*. Why say "generally"? Granted, every storyboard has *at least* one VC and *only* one entry point that means a root(?) VC. But since I personally do not use storyboards (too old school), what scenario am I missing that you see? TIA.

Comment: @dfd - When I say that it “generally has a unique view controller class”, my point is that the view controller used by a scene does not technically have to be unique to that particular scene, i.e. it can be used by other scenes, too. For example, your storyboard could have more than one nav bar controller scene on it, each using `UINavigationController`. And, while it’s not very common (and there aren’t many situations where I’d recommend it), you technically could reuse your own `UIViewController` subclass as the base class for multiple IB scenes, too. Certainly IB doesn’t prohibit it.

Answer (score 1):

A view controller can and probably will contain multiple views apart from the root view it has. That means that usually a view controller owns one ore more views that are subview's of it's own root view. Those views are often also controlled by the same view controller.

When coming from the storyboard most items you see are actually representations of view controllers (others are placeholders). "Login Quiz" sounds like a *screen* in conceptual terms, so (without knowing your details) it would probably make sense to create a LoginQuizViewController.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a lot for me. I really appreciate it!